# How can I stub a constructor in node.js using sinon in a Cloud Functions for Firebase project?

Tags: node.js, firebase, sinon, google-cloud-functions, geofire

I'm using GeoFire in a Cloud Functions for Firebase project I want to unit test.

In my original code GeoFire is used like this:

```
GeoFire = request('geofire');

...

var catGeoFire = new GeoFire(catGeofireRef);
return catGeoFire.set(storeId, [lat, lon]).then( () => {
    console.log("Added store " + storeId + " to GeoFire" );
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
```

I need to stub both the call to the GeoFire constructor and the GeoFire().set() method.

I tried:

```
const geofireStub = sinon.stub(GeoFire, 'set').resolves();
```

But I received the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property set
```

I also tried:

```
const setStub = sinon.stub().resolves();
const geofireStub = sinon.stub(GeoFire).returns({set: setStub});
```

And I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property set
```

Both errors happen at the geofireStub line.

Reading the sinon documentation I understood that I can stub an object's methods. However in this case GeoFire isn't an object; it is a constructor function. So I don't really know how can I stub it without having an associated object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this, using [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire):

```js
// target.js
var GeoFire = require('geofire');

var catGeoFire = new GeoFire(catGeofireRef);
return catGeoFire.set(storeId, [lat, lon]).then(() => {
  console.log("Added store " + storeId + " to GeoFire" );
  return Promise.resolve();
});


// test.js
var GeoFire = require('geofire');
var rewire = require('rewire')
var target = rewire('./target')

describe('target', () => {
  it('test case', () => {
    // arrange

    // configure instance
    var geoFireStub = sinon.createStubInstance(GeoFire)
    geoFireStub.set.resolves()

    // configure constuctor
    var GeoFireMock = sinon.stub().returns(geoFireStub)

    // 'GeoFire' is a mocked variable here
    var revert = rewire('GeoFire', GeoFireMock)

    // act (call tested module)
    target()

    // assert (should is just for example)
    should(GeoFireMock).calledWithNew(/* params*/)
    should(geoFireStub.set).calledWith(/* params*/)

    //cleanup (rewire and stubs, prefer to use sandbox)
    revert();
    ...

  })
})
```

Comment: oooh nice answer, thank you! This works! :-) I've managed to solve the issue by creating an additional module which required and exported the GeoFire module, so I could do something like: const geofireStub = sinon.stub(modules, 'GeoFire').returns({set: setStub}). That actually worked, but I think your solution is better and also seems to correctly interpret what is a stub and how to create them.

Comment: ugh sorry, I found out I was testing incorrectly. I had my code working by creating a new module which contained the geofire module, as I explained above. When I changed my code to be like yours I received the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolves' of undefined" from the geoFireStub.set.resolves() line.

Comment: You need to make sure that GeoFire is a constructor and geoFireStub contains all prototype methods (via stubs). Just use console.log to see that geoFireStub is

Comment: I logged GeoFire and obtained the following description: { [Function: GeoFire] distance: [Function] }

Comment: could you share target and test files via github gists?

Comment: "prefer to use sandbox" -- an illustration of how would be appreciated by many, I'm sure

Answer (score 1):

`GeoFire` is the constructor, but `set` is an instance method.
You should stub `GeoFire.prototype` I believe.

```js
sinon.stub(GeoFire.prototype, 'set').resolves();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and still receive the same "Cannot stub non-existent own property set" error. Also, I will need to stub the constructor call itself...